# C# Refactoring with dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring, factory

Trying to refactor some old code full of anti-patterns, bad code, and 10 years of piling up things with almost no remorse. There are a bunch of questions, so pardon me for this *conceptual* mess.

It is a text editor with scripting capabilities (Python and other), custom scripting language, access to databases and much more. Maybe nothing different from what Office, LibreOffice or similar do.

**1.-** First, I need to keep track of all those objects, parsing the text and creating a list of what I have called "DocumentObject":

E.g.:

- [*variable*] represents a variable
- [<py>*code*</py>] represents a python script

When the "parser" finds a match in the text (based on regex patterns), it creates a DocumentObject according to its type and stores its Regex Match.

Having different DocumentObject types (variables, scripts, database calls,...), I was thinking about creating different DocumentObject classes based on those types (i.e.: DocumentObjectVariable, DocumentObjectScript, DocumentObjectData, and so on).

```
    public class DocumentObject : IDocumentObject
    {
        public DocumentObjectType DocumentObjectType { get; set; } = DocumentObjectType.None;
        
        // RegEx Match to store position and value of found 'language pattern'
        public Match Match { get; set; }

        public DocumentObject(DocumentObjectType documentObjectType, Match match)
        {
            DocumentObjectType = documentObjectType;
            Match = match;
        }

    }
```

Until now I was not using interfaces, only deriving from DocumentObject base class. But now I want to know if using DI or factory method is the way to go.

For now, it is a basic:
`documentObjectList.Add(new DocumentObject(DocumentObjectType.Variable, match));`

So, having a required constructor parameter (at least the RegEx Match)...I need to know which is the optimal pattern or approach.

**2.-** Once the "tracking" (parse) part is completed, the next step is to *Run* the document to replace all those found DocumentObject with its different type behaviours (e.g: [*variable*] will be replaced by its actual value ([*name*] -> John))

For the sake of optimal coding, it is better to add, for example, an *Execute* method in the DocumentObject class or let a Service / Handler / Controller like class to handle all the process?

```
public Task<string> Execute()
{
    // Do whatever, like getting the variable value or executing a script

    // return the final string that will replace the DocumentObject Match in the text
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your example what you expect DI to do.

Comment: @DavidL you are right, I wasn't able to be accurate. The main point is: given a list of objects if it is better to define methods in them or to delegate in another class that will proccess them. And about the objects creation if, in this case, it is better a "normal" instantiation or use a factory (or DI if at the end I need some dependency). Maybe the question was more about principles and I ended up mixing concepts (that evidently I first have to clarify for myself).  I think that what I was looking for is Jonathan Dodds answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want the code to be [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I'm also going to assume that when you say 're-factoring' you mean that you are creating tests that show that the code produces the same 'results' before and after the implementation changes.

The 'D' in SOLID is the "dependency inversion principle" (DIP). Dependency injection (DI) can help you implement dependency inversion (DIP) but DIP and DI are different concepts.

Because the question seems to be about design advice, I will offer the following general suggestions:

- Prefer to use interfaces for polymorphism, over inheritance.
- You might use a factory class that can produce different types of objects for the same interface.
- Avoid having a property that represents the type. The object itself is its type. (i.e. Don't have the `DocumentObjectType` property.)
- Avoid `switch` statements on the object type. (i.e. Don't have a `switch` on `obj.DocumentObjectType`.) Try to put the code from each switch block into each type of object. e.g. an `IPet` interface may have a `Vocalize()` method. You can call `myPet.Vocalize()` regardless of whether the instance is actually a `Dog` (which may 'bark') or a `Cat` (which may 'meow'). (Admittedly a bad example but hopefully illustrates the point.)
- Prefer composition over inheritance to share common code. i.e. Instead of derived classes that share code in a base class that provides access to certain data, 'inject' a data provider class into each instance. (This is where a DI container helps. It can be the factory and cache for the providers.)
- My preference is to inject dependencies via the constructor. An object should be useable if it is constructed (and the constructor should fail if the object won't be useable.)
- Finally don't try to change everything all at once. It's not an all-or-nothing situation. Tackle the challenge in small steps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this "guide" is what I need to start. I am used to code without thinking too much about SOLID (ok, nothing at all). For now a factory with at least the Match parameter seems ok, if I don't break any law :). I will try to deal later with the eventual different parameters needed for each DocumentObject type (and thanks for pointing out to remove the DocumentObjectType prop, a bad habit of mine).